# Relating classes of computational complexity to finding solution to classes of algebraic equations

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, algebraic-complexity

Having related classes of computational complexity to finding solution to classes of  algebraic equations, we may relate classes of computational complexity  to  algebraic geometry or complex geometry, is there any reference for the relationshi? like Schemes relating to classes of CC, or something else